# Review not showing after submitting in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I have wrote below code to do rating and review in my `detailpage` with `API`. Once I submit the review and comment. The data is not showing at same time. If I move to back page and again come to `detailpage` then data is showing. That is in `Myreview` and `All review` section. How to show data after click on same page at same time?. Please help.

Below is ts file

```
reviewComment(elm){
     this.commentValue = elm.comment;
     console.log(this.commentValue);

       this.authService.securePostData("listing_id="+this.listing.id+"&rating="+this.starValue+"&comment="+this.commentValue,"review/add",).then((result) => {
             this.reviewResult = result;
              let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                  message: 'Review added successfully',
                  duration: 4500,
                  position: 'bottom'
                });

                toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
                  console.log('Dismissed toast');
                });

                toast.present();
             console.log(result);

       })
}

myReview(){

       if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userStorage')) != null) {

       this.authService.securePostData("listing_id="+this.listing.id,"myreview",).then((result) => {
             this.myreviews = result;
             this.myreview = this.myreviews.review;

             console.log(this.myreview);

       })
       }
}

allReview(){


       this.authService.postData("listing_id="+this.listing.id,"reviews",).then((result) => {

            var resData = result['data'];
            this.allreview = [];
            resData.forEach(element => {
              var dd = new Date(element.created_at);
              element.ogdate = ("0" + dd.getDate()).slice(-2)+"-"+("0" + (dd.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+"-"+dd.getFullYear();
              this.allreview.push(element);
            });
       })
}
```

this is html

```
      <ion-row *ngIf="!myreview?.id">
     <ion-col class="addrev">
           <div style="font-size: 22px;">Add Review</div>            
        <rating (click)="reviewStar(this)" [(ngModel)]="rate"
        readOnly="false" 
        max="5" 
        emptyStarIconName="star-outline" 
        halfStarIconName="star-half" 
        starIconName="star" 
        nullable="false"
        > 
        </rating>
        <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="comment"></ion-textarea>
        <button ion-button (click)="reviewComment(this)">Submit Review</button>
     </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row class="myreviws" *ngIf="myreview?.id > 0">
    <h4>My Review</h4>
     <ion-item>
        <ion-grid>
           <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-3>
                 <img src="{{myreview?.user.profile_image}}">
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-9>
                 <span class="name">{{myreview?.user.name}}</span>
                 <p class="rating">
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="myreview?.rating > 0"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="myreview?.rating > 1"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="myreview?.rating > 2"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="myreview?.rating > 3"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="myreview?.rating > 4"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="myreview?.rating < 1"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="myreview?.rating < 2"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="myreview?.rating < 3"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="myreview?.rating < 4"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="myreview?.rating < 5"></ion-icon>
                    {{myreview?.ogdate}}
                 </p>
                 <p class="comment">{{myreview?.comment}}</p>
              </ion-col>
           </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
     </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
    <h4>All Reivew</h4>
  <ion-row class="allreviws" *ngFor="let allreviews of allreview">
     <ion-item>
        <ion-grid>
           <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-3>
                 <img src="{{allreviews.user.profile_image}}">
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-9>
                 <span class="name">{{allreviews.user.name}}</span>
                 <p class="rating">
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="allreviews.rating > 0"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="allreviews.rating > 1"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="allreviews.rating > 2"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="allreviews.rating > 3"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star" *ngIf="allreviews.rating > 4"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="allreviews.rating < 1"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="allreviews.rating < 2"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="allreviews.rating < 3"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="allreviews.rating < 4"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon ios="ios-star-outline" md="md-star-outline" *ngIf="allreviews.rating < 5"></ion-icon>
                    {{allreviews.ogdate}}
                 </p>
                 <p class="comment">{{allreviews.comment}}</p>
              </ion-col>
           </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
     </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
```

Comment: in what kind of html element or ionic component do you display your data? some of them need to be updated manually.

Comment: I have added my html code

Comment: if i understood you right and you try to refresh the whole data displayed in your html you could try something like this:
this.myreviews = [];
this.myreviews = result;
this.myreview = undefined;
this.myreview = this.myreviews.review;
sometimes this helps to let Ionic refresh the Data. If not than try to set the new data in a timeout.